# Is it possible to set table option depending on screen size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to know if we can a set using Javascript, multiple table option
For example, if there is a table like this:

```
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>bla bla</td>
<td>bla bla</td>
<td>bla bla</td>
<td>bla bla</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

So, if a screen size is over `1200px` it should show all 4 `td` element on one line
if screen size is between `800px` and `1200px` it should show only 3 `td` on one line
if screen size is between `500px` and `800px` it should show only 2 `td` on one line
and if it is less than `500px` it should show only one `td` on one line

I know how to show only last option, less thank `500px` i can add in CSS  `display:block`

But is it possible to make 4 variant?

Comment: you can set the width with `%`. `33%` for 3 tds, `50%` for 2 tds

Comment: just to clear my mind... you want to keep the table intact, that is to say showing and hiding cells, or adding and removing cells?

Comment: No, i want to make responsive table.

Comment: maybe this helps you: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Answer (score 0):

you cant make like css media queries with js using an event listener to window resize and checking how many columns display depending on the window width. or maybe with just css display: none and some media queries

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to accomplish what you are trying to do without using javascript, and using media queries instead.

I good primer (tutorial) on media queries can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).